# What is the Syntax for ! Page.IsPostBack

Tags: vb.net

In my program ! Page.IsPostBack is not executing. So, Please tell me that What is the actual Syntax to write it?

`If Not Page.IsPostBack = False Then 
       Session("FirstDate") = Nothing 
       Dim smonth As Integer = System.DateTime.Now.Month 
       ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = smonth - 1 
       Dim Yearid As Integer = System.DateTime.Now.Year 
       ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(Yearid.ToString()).Selected = True 
       Dim smmonth As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(ddlMonth.SelectedValue) 
       Dim Year As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(ddlYear.SelectedValue) 
       Dim day As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, smmonth) 
     End If`

This code is not executing when page is loading first time. System is not giving any kind of error and in my openion the code is right but Nevertheless it is not working in my website..

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this question?

Comment: Your question doesn't supply enough information. In what context are you using this code? Under what circumstances do you expect it to execute?

Answer (score 1):

If you're converting from `C#`, that would be `Not Page.IsPostback`.

---

Based on your updated code, you've got too much negation going on. You want:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
```

Your current expression takes `Page.IsPostback`, which will be `False` for the first request and `True` for every subsequent one. You then apply `Not` to that, so `Not Page.IsPostback` will be `True` for the first request and `False` for every other request. But then, you compare the result of that to `False`, which is effectively the same as doing another `Not`.

You don't *have* to have a comparison in every `If` statement. If you find yourself writing either `= False` or `= True` in an `If`, it's an indication that you're typing too much. `X = True` can just be `X`. `X = False` can just be replaced with `Not X`.

Comment: Can you check my code if I will give you this code. Please

Comment: If you want help with "not working" then you should edit your question and include more than a fragment of one line of code. You should also be specific about **how** it's not working. Is it giving you unexpected results? Tell us what the inputs were, what result you expected and what actually happened. Do you get an error message? Tell us **what** error message you're getting.

Comment: If Not Page.IsPostBack = False Then
            Session("FirstDate") = Nothing
            Dim smonth As Integer = System.DateTime.Now.Month
            ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = smonth - 1
            Dim Yearid As Integer = System.DateTime.Now.Year
            ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(Yearid.ToString()).Selected = True
            Dim smmonth As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)
            Dim Year As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(ddlYear.SelectedValue)
            Dim day As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, smmonth)
        End If

Comment: This is my code and it is not executing in the website.

Comment: As I said **edit** your question to include the code. There's a `{}` button that causes the code to be nicely formatted. Code in comments is unreadable. And again, you need to be clearer on what "not working" or "not executing" actually means.

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
```

is the same as

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
```

You are combine the two together by doing this

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack = False Then
```

Which is equivalent to

```
If Page.IsPostBack = True Then
```